# GUI softwares/netbeans-plugins for creating branches/tags in svn?

Tags: svn, netbeans

hi i wonder if there are some GUI softwares to administrate a svn repo?

or do you actually have to log into the ubuntu server with ssh and use all the svn commands to copy the trunk to a branch, merge the data back and forth, copy to a tag, delete and so on.

im using netbeans in mac. i think it's only handling the communication between a local project and the repo. not the flows between trunc, branch and tag (creating, deleting, viewing differences etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a branch by right clicking on a project and then selecting Subversion -> Copy To, there you can select a remote folder.

For more information about Subversion in NetBeans see:
http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/subversion.html

Comment: so i have to check out from /trunk to a local work copy..and then copy this one to a remote folder?

Comment: yes, the remote folder is where you want your branch on the repository, you then need to switch your local working copy to point to this branch. look at some open source projects for common SVN file structure, its usually in the form of /trunk, /branches, /tags.

Answer (score 0):

For checking out, branching, merging, etc I would recommend you learn the command-line svn tools for Mac OS-X. That way you can do all of this stuff directly from your box if you choose. Although these tools are a bit intimidating at first, once you understand the concepts they are straightforward and about as easy as a GUI such as Tortoise SVN.

As far as checkins and viewing history is concerned, you should have no problem doing that directly from netbeans. And you will have the best experience using netbeans directly for this stuff, anyway.